# Error when execute gcloud

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have error when I run google cloud command, this is the error message which I get

```
$ gcloud compute instances list

NAME ZONE MACHINE_TYPE INTERNAL_IP EXTERNAL_IP STATUS
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.list) Some requests did not succeed:
 - Access Not Configured. The API is not enabled for your project, or there is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration.
```

I have two machine running and I already updated to new version.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if you are encountering this problem, but if you specify the project name instead of the project ID when you do "gcloud config set project " then you will currently get the "Access Not Configured" error. I've pointed it out on the #gcloud IRC so hopefully it gets fixed. There may be other issues like this so it is best to ensure your parameters are sane.

Comment: that was the solution!

Answer (score 3):

If your project hasn't been marked for abuse and/or deletion, you have to enable 'Google Compute Engine' API in the [Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/) to solve the problem.

Comment: Just an FYI for future readers who may see this answer first: This is only one possible solution. I was getting this error and my API was already enabled. David Aiken's answer below ended up solving it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Configure your project using following command

```
gcloud config set project <project-id>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact API we need to enable in order to get rid of this error

> Compute Engine API